# parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have been trying to send an Email from a contact form using Ajax.

When the mail is sent, It should return a confirmation message :
"thank you for contacting us".

Instead of displaying this message i have an error:

```
{"type":"success","message":"thank you for contacting us"} parsererror    SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 8
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at parseJSON (jquery.js:4)
at On (jquery.js:6)
at k (jquery.js:6)
at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.js:6)`
```

Here is my PHP File sending the mail:

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$okMessage = 'thank you for contacting us';


$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$societe = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['societe']));
$num = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['num']));

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Entreprise: ' . $societe . "\n\n" . 'contact Tel: ' . $num . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'xxxxx'; 
$mail->Port = xx; //
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->Username = "xxxx"; 
$mail->Password = "xxxx"; 


$mail->setFrom('xxxx','xxxx'); 
$mail->addAddress('xxxx'); 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->send();

header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
'type' => 'success',
'message' => $okMessage
);
echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Here is my JS function

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');

    var req = $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
                }
    });

    req.done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){

        console.log( data, textStatus, jqXHR );
        console.warn( jqXHR.responseText);
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });

    req.fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown );
        console.warn( jqXHR.responseText);
        form_status.html('<p class="text-error">' + textStatus + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Look at the raw response in the Network tab to see if there's anything around the JSON part of the response.

Comment: {"type":"success","message":"thank you for contacting us"} this is what I have in my Network tab @Barmar

Comment: @AthMav what is port string please ?

Comment: @AthMav Why should a port number be a string? And what does that have to do with parsing the JSON response?

Comment: @AthMav The documentation shows using a number: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleasmtp

Comment: $mail->Port = 25;  this is the port string in my phpmailer function @AthMav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

In the network tab of my browser, i saw that the response was not only Json.

I realised that it was caused by the parameter

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

In fact, it returned me the whole conversation between Server and Client, before printing the response in JSON.
So I replace it by

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

and every thing is ok now.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is really helpful. I was having the same problem until I find this solution.